# powershell 2.0 import task from win server 2003 schtasks /query /fo csv

Tags: powershell, windows-task-scheduler

I need to export the task list from a windows 2003 server to 2008.
I used schtasks /query /fo csv to export the tasks into a csv file from the 2003 host.

Now I need to find out how to import the tasks to the 2008 server. I found a couple of posts here but they were not very relevant because I am using Powershell 2.0 and I don't have any extra powershell module available nor I'm allowed to make any change on the powershell configuration either.

Does anyone know how can I import the task to the 2008 machine ?

Here's an example of what the tasks look like in the csv file :

```
"TaskName","Next Run Time","Status"
"backup_task","12:00:00 AM, 6/29/2012",""
"backup_task_montly","2:00:00 AM, 6/30/2012",""
"backup_task_weekly","1:00:00 AM, 7/1/2012",""
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: take a look here: http://serverfault.com/questions/43874/is-there-a-way-to-import-a-scheduled-task-from-windows-2003-job-to-windows-20

Comment: Thanks very much for your link Christian!
Unfortunately, the 2 servers are not on the same network. 
I have no choice other than recreate all the tasks I am afraid. There are not that many of them so that's OK.

For the record, I don't understand why it is such a hassle to export a simple list of scheduled task on Windows wen you can simply copy a cron file on unix systems. 

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried working with the scheduler directly through COM objects?  Here's an article I've referenced in the past for some sample code.

http://www.send4help.net/syncing-scheduled-tasks-with-powershell-901